# Distribution of C++ application with dependencies in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, dependencies

I'm a junior programmer. I have developed a Visual Studio C++ project with a fair amount of dependencies: Boost, a fingerprint recognition library and Windows Biometrics Frameworks. As for today I know the Windows Biometric Framework can be downloaded from the standard Windows Update and I am not concerned about that, to my knowledge, the application is ready to search and link WBF dependencies on the computer by itself.

My concern is: which is the easiest (not most efficient, I need speed here) way to pack the executable file with all the resources and dependencies this .exe needs (Boost and the fingerprint recognition SDK) so that I can minimize distribution troubles, i.e this dll is missing, please reinstall the application, and things like that, without having to compile everything in the client's computer?

I've been able to see a couple ways here: copy the dlls listed in the project config, change to static linking... but I don't know if that is the simplest way. I have little to no trust in my abilities for this and those methods seem quite manual, wondering if there might be an automatic way for doing these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the fingerprint library or WBF, but most of Boost resides in headers so its compiled in when you compile your application. Some, like the threading library and system specific calls(e.g. getting CPU core count) are libraries that are statically linked to.

What format of the fingerprint library is provided? Dynamically, there would be at least a .dll with a corresponding import .lib file. Your application links statically to the importer after compiling, and binds to the library during run time. Or the library can be included in one large, single .lib that's linked to your application after its compiled. If you have both options available and you only want to distribute the binary file, use static linking.

Comment: Thank you, I understood that I had to learn first the logic behind linking. Or at least there is no other way around found in this thread. Anyway, I found my dependencies. With static linking I don't need to provide any lib files in the project, and there was one DLL library that I had to provide to the executable file. Im accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like in any systems, you will need to include every .dll libraries your app links and every external resources(images, config files, ...) your app uses. I usually make my Windows distributions by using http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php.
Very easy to use.

Comment: Eventually the project was not so complicated and learnt to link my libraries. Thank you for the suggestion!